# Jinterface not allowing java node to intiaite messaging

Tags: erlang, jinterface

I start my Erlang node with:

```
erl -sname erlangNode -cookie secret

P = spawn( fun() -> receive _ -> io:format("gotit") end end).
register(java_server, P).
```

Then I run my java node client code:

```
OtpNode node = new OtpNode("bingo", "secret");
OtpMbox mbox = node.createMbox("com");

System.out.println( node.ping("erlangNode@localhost",2000) );

mbox.send("java_server", "localhost",new OtpErlangAtom("hej"));
```

But the Erlang process java_server never receives the message.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your java node outputs true on ping message?
Maybe you forgot to write whole node name in send?

```
mbox.send("java_server", "erlangNode@localhost",new OtpErlangAtom("hej"));
```